# Is my accelerometer precise enough?

Tags: noise, signal-analysis, software-implementation

I have a device with an accelerometer and I want to make it as precise as possible (using algorithms). Currently no DSP algorithm is running - I am reading values as they are. I've made 3 tests - in each I rotated the device around one of the axes and recorded the values coming out from accelerometer. It would be perfect if each of the tests would produce a perfect circle; this would mean no further calibration is needed. **The desired precision is +- 10mg (+- 1%). For example, the mean value when Z axis is maximal is 1024mg. 1010mg would be acceptable.**

Below are the results of tests ([Matlab copy-paste to display](http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=kw0UmtHP)). Is it enough to test the three axes or should I also test the cases where the gravity gets distributed in all of the axes? Further; what approach would you suggest considering calibration to 1% precision (please be specific).

I need a thorough answer on this topic.

**Rotation around X axis:**
[image: X-axis]

**Round Y axis:**

[image: Y-axis]

**Round Z axis:**

[image: Z-axis]

Comment: Precise enough for *what* ? What is the requirement, i.e. what are you trying to achieve ?

Comment: I am making an AHRS for a plane. I would like to make the accelerometer as precise as possible software-wise.

Comment: Unless you define the required precision in some meaningful way then it's impossible to answer the question.

Comment: I will rethink what my desired precision is and report back ASAP ;)

Comment: Alright, the desired precision is +- 10mg, that is 1%. I've updated the question too.

Comment: So does the measured data meet your specification?

Comment: No, I already wrote that currently I have 2-3% of an error (1024mg).

Comment: Sorry, your sentence above was a bit hard to parse. So what you're saying is that at the maximum Z axis value, you expect $1.0 g$ to be reported, and it reports $1.024 g$ instead. Do you have a datasheet for the sensor? What are its expected accuracy characteristics? That is important, because even if you could gin up some calibration scheme to make the unit you're using look suitable, there might not be any guarantee that the next one off the production line will work for you.

Comment: http://www.pololu.com/file/download/LSM303DLH-compass-app-note.pdf?file_id=0J434

Answer (score 4):

Typically you can improve performance by analyzing the data that you want and analyzing the data that you don't want. I would assume that a plane can't turn infinitely fast so the actual "want" data is properly fairly band limited. Depending on how fast you are sampling the accelerometer you may pick up a lot of "out of bandwidth" noise. This could easily be improved with a low pass filter or some moving average contraption.  The more you know about the properties of the actual signal and the properties of the noise, the better you can separate the two.